# Red element in VSC

Tags: html, colors

Newbie here!

So I am currently coding in Visual Studio Code and for some reason when I type `<element>` into my code it shows up with red color and I know this seems stupid but it had different color and somehow it changed all of a sudden from light blue to red and everything looks bad. I don´t know if it´s cause of some error somewhere but everything shows as fine. Yes it´s just a minor thing that I should get over but it really bugs me and I don´t know how to change the color of it back.

Comment: It is possible that you have a html tag not  properly closed, or one missing in your markup. Can you post a screenshot or a snippet of your code?

Comment: [link]https://imgur.com/a/7OB62eR the one on the left is whole new document

Comment: <element> tag is specific for XML Markup Language [link]https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp . As i can see from the left image line 1, you are writing HTML5 code (<!DOCTYPE html>), so don't use <element> but <div> instead, or whatever suits you.

Comment: @GhighiEftimie thanks! But when I do that I can´t show JS variables anymore... Is there a way around it?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't show JS variables"? What is you JS code?

Comment: I use <element> tag for showing variables in html and if I get rid of them I can´t show them on my page anymore